# How do I do Skype calls using Fring

Tags: skype, fring

I have read that Fring supports doing Skype calls. I have installed Fring it but see no Skype options.

How do I do Skype calls using Fring?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Skype has blocked Fring from using it's services. For more info see http://www.fring.com/blog/?p=2322

Answer (score 0):

So, even though Fring supports Skype calls, Skype won't have any of it. Skype blocks calls from Fring now, so the mobile app no longer includes that functionality. However, there is a [Skype](http://www.skype.com/intl/en-us/get-skype/on-your-mobile/skype-mobile/android/) for Android app...

**Update:**
And, now the Skype app is [available](http://blogs.skype.com/en/2010/10/android.html?cm_mmc=socialm%7Ctwitter-_-global%7Cintl%7Cen-_-skype-_-android%7Cannouncement) for everyone except those in China and Japan.

Comment: Unfortunately those calls (skype out) still use your cell minutes.

Comment: @Matt, Good point.

Comment: Verizon wireless only, I live in New Zealand, actually it turns out that most of the world doesn't live in the states.

Comment: Sorry, I guess? Actually, it turns out you didn't say where you were...